# counter for errors

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement

when user logs out the user may choose to log back in again. For Logging back in: If the user get the pin code wrong 3 times, the program terminates.

```
System.out.println("You have logged out");
System.out.print("Please Enter Pin: ");  
pin2 = sc.nextInt();
while (pin != pin2){
   while (ctr < 2){
   System.out.print("Please Enter Pin: ");
   pin2 = sc.nextInt();
   ctr++;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Can you remove everything not necessary and tell us exactly what your problem is? Maybe what you want is `while (pin == pin2)`

Comment: What it the problem with this code?? it is not stopping after 5 ??

Comment: Get rid of that label! Do it now ... *shudder*. If you want to end the loop, set a boolean to false which you check in the while condition.

Comment: Using Labels and/or goto rep. named breaks is commonly considered bad practice and sometimes even harmful (at least in java + many other high level languages). There are very rare cases where they have no alternative and in my 10+ years in Java I have never felt the need to use one.

Comment: @jankigadhiya it does stop  at 5 but what i want to do is after the user picks "1" then the program will ask again what transaction the user wants to do. "what transac would you want to do..." "1" "(code in 1)" "what transac would you want to do.." "3"

Comment: It is not asking again you are saying ??

Comment: @jankigadhiya yes the program doesnt ask again and it just keeps on going to next case for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what been said in the comments, avoid using Labels and/or goto rep.
Use something like that :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AtmMachine {

public static void main(String[] args){

    int actualPin = -1;
    int sel = 0, pin, pin2, check, ctr = 0, dep, with, bal = 10000;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(actualPin == -1)
    {
    System.out.print("Please enter a new pin: ");
    pin = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Please verify your new pin: ");
    pin2 = sc.nextInt();
    if(pin == pin2) actualPin = pin;
    else System.out.println("Error");
    }

    boolean logged = false;

    while (true){

    if(logged){
    System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
    System.out.println("1 - Check Balance");
    System.out.println("2 - Deposite");
    System.out.println("3 - Withdraw");
    System.out.println("4 - Change Pin");
    System.out.println("5 - End Transaction");
    sel = sc.nextInt();
    switch (sel){
        case 1: 
            System.out.println("Your current balance is "+ bal);
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("How much would you want to deposite? ");
            dep = sc.nextInt();
            bal= dep+bal;
            System.out.println("Your new current balance is "+ bal);
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("How much would you want to Withdraw? ");
            with = sc.nextInt();

            if(with > bal){
            System.out.println("You do not have that amount on your account! Please enter again.");
            }
            else{
            System.out.println("You withdrew "+ with);
            bal = bal-with;
            System.out.println("Your new current balance is "+ (bal));
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.print("Please enter a new pin: ");
            pin = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Please verify your new pin: ");
            pin2 = sc.nextInt();
            if(pin == pin2) actualPin = pin;
            else System.out.println("Error");
            break;
        case 5:
            logged = false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Please Enter Pin: ");
        sel = sc.nextInt();
        logged = actualPin == sel;
    }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly you will want to have something like that:

```
while (pin == pin2) {
        System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("1 - Check Balance");
        System.out.println("2 - Deposite");
        System.out.println("3 - Withdraw");
        System.out.println("4 - Change Pin");
        System.out.println("5 - End Transaction");
        sel = sc.nextInt();

        switch (sel) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Your current balance is " + bal);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("How much would you want to deposite? ");
                dep = sc.nextInt();
                bal = dep + bal;
                System.out.println("Your new current balance is " + bal);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("How much would you want to Withdraw? ");
                with = sc.nextInt();

                if (with > bal) {
                    System.out.println("You do not have that amount on your                           account! Please enter again.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You withdrew " + with);
                    bal = bal - with;
                    System.out.println("Your new current balance is " + (bal));
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.print("Please enter a new pin: ");
                pin = sc.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Please verify your new pin: ");
                pin2 = sc.nextInt();
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Please Enter Pin: ");
                pin = sc.nextInt();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Basically, I've deleted the `loop` label, it is not necessary and I consider it a bad style. I've also changed the while condition, so the program runs as long as user enters exactly the same pin as he confirmed at the beginning. Moreover, I think it is better to read the value of `sel` after printing instructions, not before as you did.

Comment: Please enter a new pin: 1234
Please verify your new pin: 1234
What would you like to do?
1 - Check Balance
2 - Deposite
3 - Withdraw
4 - Change Pin
5 - End Transaction
1
Your current balance is 10000
How much would you want to deposite?

Comment: thats what happens when i run it. its actually the same as mine. i dont get why it automatically goes to case 2 instead of asking again what the user wants to do